# Como copiar el prototipo window?

Tags: javascript, prototipos

Como puedo heredar las propiedades y todos los métodos de de window a un objeto creado por mi ?

Ya que por ejemplo para esto:

```
window.addEventListener();
```

Me gustaría hacerla pequeña para usarla habitualmente a:

```
var myObject = Object.create(window.prototype);
myObject.v = myObject.addEventListener;
```

Entonces luego realizar:

```
myObject.v("click",function(){});
```

Que seria equivalente a realizar:

```
window.addEventListener("click",function(){});
```

Solo que una sintaxis, más corta.

***Es esto posible ? y cómo?***

**PD: No quiero realizar una por una, a esto me refiero con:**

```
function s(e,func,i = false) {
window.addEventListener(e.toString(),func, i);
}
```

**Sino que, heredar totalmente todos sus metodos.**

Comment: Para eso tendrias que definir que nombres ponerle a CADA UNA de las propiedades nuevas.

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que no quiero hacer

Comment: Lo que me refiero es que si solamente quieres hacerlo para la funcion addEventListener??

Comment: No , para todos sus métodos y propiedades

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es, que si quieres cambiar la sintaxis a una mas corta de TODAS las propiedades y metodos, como es que no quieres definir antes que nombres darles...

Comment: Me refiero a básicamente, cambiarle el nombre al objeto, desde window.addEventListener a w.addEventListener, pero como obtengo los metodos de window ? ese es mi problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según tengo entendido lo único que deseas hacer es crear un alias del objeto `window` y un alias a la función `addEventListener`

## Primera opción (recomendada)

```js
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, 'w', {
    configurable: true, 
    get: function(){return this}
})
Object.defineProperty(Window.prototype, 'v', {
    configurable: true, 
    value: Window.prototype.addEventListener
})

w.v('DOMContentLoaded', function(){alert('Hola mundo')}, false)
```

## Segunda opción (No recomendada)

```js
var w = window
var v = Window.prototype.addEventListener.bind(w)

w.v('DOMContentLoaded', function(){alert('Hola mundo')}, false)
```

El primer código crea:

- Un alias del objeto `window`, ahora accesible a través del símbolo `w`
- Un alias para la función `addEventListener`, ahora accesible a través del símbolo `v` en el prototipo de `Window`

El segundo código crea:

- Un alias del objeto `window`, ahora accesible a través del símbolo `w`
- Una función compuesta, la cuál se le ha enlazado el objeto `w` como la referencia en `this`

Sea cuál se la opción elegida si se tiene el código

```
window.addEventListener(...)
```

Se puede reemplazar indistintamente por

```
w.v(...)
```

Desconozco el uso útil a lo que planteas, salvo alguna especie rara de ofuscación de código.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, por qué la segunda función no la recomiendas?

Comment: El primer código efectivamente crea un alias de `addEventListener` dentro del prototipo `WindowPrototype` esto quiere decir que si creas un nuevo objeto con `new Window(..)` éste también contendrá ese alias. El segundo código, crea el alias únicamente para la instancia particular `window` y no para el resto.

Comment: Eduen por si puedes responderme, por qué le defines la propiedad al prototipo de window?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian es por semántica, la ventaja de definir una propiedad en el prototipo es que ésta es única y será compartida por toda las instancias del mismo constructor. La referencia en `this` también cambiará, en lugar de ser el scope global se recibirá la instancia particular del objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la lista de metodos que tiene el objeto `window` basta con hacer:

```
for (var i in window) {
    if (typeof window[i] === 'function') {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```